# Expression for a frustrated, annoyed double-take

Tags: phrase-requests

Let us take a specific situation.

> You are facing a person you find extremely annoying. The person is finding faults in your ways and pointing them out in a rather blunt manner. They are making high demands, being obnoxious and really getting under your skin. Worst of all, they are right on all accounts and your argument with that person is quickly turning into a losing battle.
>
> And on top of that, the person is using a really annoying dialect, something you can't hold against them but it really brushes you the wrong way.
>
> Yet another point in your argument is raised, stated in that annoying dialect, and as you utter your angry, frustrated (and wrong) rebuttal, you find yourself replying using the same terrible dialect. You stop and correct yourself immediately, but during the second before correcting yourself, you...

*scoff*? The dictionary definition suggests scoffing is more similar to annoyed, dismissive laugh. This is more about grinding your teeth in frustration. How would you describe such an expression?

Comment: Tough question... "suffer in silence"? There's a quote that seems apropos, "Never argue with an idiot. They drag you down to their level then beat you with experience." - Greg King

Comment: Are you talking about the moment you realize you're using the same dialect and worry that they think you're mocking them?

Comment: Your boss sounds like a difficult person to work for.

Comment: @Kristina: No, the moment when you realize the person got so deep under your skin you begin thinking like them - and as result talking like them. "Wrapped you around their finger" so to say.

Comment: @SoylentGreen: Luckily this is for a fictional character. My boss has no funny accent of any kind ;)

Comment: Why not accept grimace ?

Comment: @Argot: I wondered if someone could come up with something *even* better, plus wanted to poll the community by means of votes to decide if it really is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might say that in the instant before you correct yourself, you *grimace*, that is, you make a face that indicates self-disgust.